# Predicted Probability and Interaction Terms

Tags: r, probability, mixed-model, interaction

This is my first time asking a question here, so apologies if I failed to include all necessary information. I have run GLMM's in the past but have limited experience with assessing interaction terms.

I have run the model below using GLMMadaptive that includes 'temperature:absolute_humidity' as a fixed interaction term and 'transect_id' as a random effect. 'Panting' is a binomial response, and the predictors are both continuous variables (numerics)

Example of the code:

```
> model <- mixed_model(Panting ~ temperature:absolute_humidity, ~ 1|transect_id, family = binomial, data = data, control = list(iter_EM=0), na.action = na.omit)
> summary(model) 

Call:
mixed_model(fixed = Panting ~ temperature:absolute_humidity, 
    random = ~1 | transect_id, data = data, family = binomial, 
    na.action = na.omit, control = list(iter_EM = 0))

Data Descriptives:
Number of Observations: 195
Number of Groups: 9 

Model:
 family: binomial
 link: logit 

Fit statistics:
  log.Lik     AIC      BIC
 -41.3629 88.7258 89.31748

Random effects covariance matrix:
              StdDev
(Intercept) 1.002911

Fixed effects:
                              Estimate Std.Err z-value   p-value
(Intercept)                    -7.7099  1.9231 -4.0092   < 1e-04
temperature:absolute_humidity   0.0081  0.0029  2.7899 0.0052725

Integration:
method: adaptive Gauss-Hermite quadrature rule
quadrature points: 11

Optimization:
method: quasi-Newton
converged: TRUE
```

The objective is to find the temperature associated with 50% predicted probability of 'Panting', while accounting for the interaction between 'temperature' and 'absolute_humidity'.

I have run similar models on 'temperature' and 'absolute_humidity' included as fixed effects (i.e. not interactions) and found the predictor value associated with 50% probability of 'Panting' as follows:

FYI, dose.p does not work for the package used hence building the below function.

```
model2 <- mixed_model(Panting ~ temperature, ~ 1|transect_id, family = binomial, data = data, control = list(iter_EM=0), na.action = na.omit)

#50% probability 
 dose.p.glmm <-  function(obj, cf = 1:2, p = 0.5) {
   f <- family(obj)
   eta <- f$linkfun(p) 
   b <- fixef(obj)[cf]
   x.p <- (eta - b[1L])/b[2L]
   names(x.p) <- paste("p = ", format(p), ":", sep = "")
   pd <- -cbind(1, x.p)/b[2L]
   SE <- sqrt(((pd %*% vcov(obj)[cf, cf]) * pd) %*% c(1, 1))
   res <- structure(x.p, SE = matrix(SE), p = p)
   class(res) <- "glm.dose"
   res
 }
 
Panting50 <- dose.p.glmm(model2)
Panting50
             Dose       SE
p = 0.5: 35.88691 2.046575
```

Where 'Dose' is the temperature associated with 50% predicted probability of 'Panting'. However, this code produces strange outputs when an interaction term is included in the model. Any ideas on how to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance!